# One to many relationship query in Django ORM, Where I want to query on One table and want to get output with many table data as a list

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

**Here is my model:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.expressions import F


class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name of publication', max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True) 

    def __str__(self):

        return f'{self.name}' 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Publication"
        verbose_name_plural = "Publications" 


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name of book', max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True) 
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books_publications', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return f'{self.name}//{self.publication.name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Book"
        verbose_name_plural = "Book"
```

**I want outcome json as single publication with list of book (Please show me using Django ORM query and Django Serializer OR using DRF):**

**Want Output JSON like below:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "publication 001",
        "book": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Book 001"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Book 002"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "publication 002",
        "book": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Book 003"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Book 004"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried it through several way but unable to solve it using django orm query. I've done it through raw query. But I wantto implement it through Django ORM Query. SO please help me. TIA

Comment: `I tried it through several way`: Like what? Post your attempts.

Comment: I tried append book queryset inside publication queryset but happened errors. I did it through custom json format dictionary using for loop also, but I think this code doesn't look good, I want to complete it using serializer. I didn't understand how can I should do query for the sample JSON outcome. So what should I do?  please suggest me. TIA

Comment: I would edit the question and add code there if I were you, instead of trying to explain it using words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick using simple serializers

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializer.CharField()
   

class PublicationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    book = BookSerializer(source="books_publications.all", many=True)

qs = Publication.objects.all()
data = PublicationSerializer(qs, many=True).data
```

`source="book_set"` allows for an object field to be mapped to a different serializer field.
`book_set` is the default [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) provided by Django. This means that
`my_publication.book_set.all()` is equivalent to `Book.objects.filter(publication=my_publication)`.
You should consider defining your own `related_name`.

```py
publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="books")
```

Note that the above code will result in N+1 queries to the database. A first one to get all publications and one for each publication to get related books.
You can and should use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to reduce the number of query to two.

```py
qs = Publication.objects.all()
qs = qs.prefetch_related("books_publications")
data = PublicationSerializer(qs, many=True).data
```

Alternatively you could use `ModelSerializer`

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("id", "name")


class PublicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = BookSerializer(source="books_publications.all", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ("id", "name", "book")
```

Comment: every thig is fine, Only one mistake that here my publication foreign key related name is "books_publications", when I changed "books_publications" instead of "book_set", then its work fine. Thanks @Alombaros

Comment: Hi @Alombaros
source="books_publications.all" --> this command is use for retrieve all data, how can I filter from all data here? Like: instead of I want book with all publication, I want book with publication id = 1?

Comment: Take a look at the `prefetch_related` method with a `Prefetch` object. With a filtered queryset and the to_attr argument, you should be able to do whatever you want

Comment: would you like to provide an example please? @Alombaros